# Difficulty showing images input by user in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having problems showing images that the user had input using cv2.imread. Tried using cv2.imshow and canvas.create_image.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageTk
import tkinter.filedialog
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.title('AutoCC')
root.geometry("600x500")

def select_image():
    global myFiles, panel

    browseFile = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames()

    if len(browseFile) > 0:
        image = cv2.imread("/")
        cv2.imshow("Images", image)

appTitle = Label(root, text="AutoCC", height = 2, font=('Colombo Sans', 40, 'bold')).pack()
fileBtn = Button(root, text="Browse Files", command=select_image).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I had errors like tuple not in range and assertion failed in the imshow function.

Comment: Please show the actual error that this code produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is currently not specifying any path as you have `image = cv2.imread("/")`.

`askopenfilenames()` returns a tuple of files, so if you wish to have multiple files then you would have to create a loop and pass one path at a time, but if you need a singe file to be selected use `askopenfilename()`, this returns a string of the file path selected.

```py
def select_image():
    global myFiles, panel

    browseFile = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()

    if len(browseFile) > 0:
        image = cv2.imread(browseFile)
        cv2.imshow("Images", image)
```

I believe this should solve the issue.